# Contact Form sometime fails to send an email

Tags: php, forms

I have a very basic contact form using `method="post"` and a php script.  For 90% of the time, it works fine. But, we have discovered that about 10% of the forms submitted have not actually sent the email.  The email should go to 3 different recipients, but none of them receive it.  When the form is submitted the user is redirected correctly to the "thank you" page so as far as they know it has been sent.

If my form did not work at all, I could understand that there would be an error with my code somewhere but to fail 10% of the time seems odd.  It has been live for almost a year and this has just started happening.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you with your problem

Comment: if you can guess my shoesize on the first try, so will I guess....